# how to display piechart on the same run?

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart, pie-chart, display

I am trying to make piecharts on run of the project. The values for piechart are being calculated and returned by a function rq of class radioques.
The piecharts forms on running the code, but they get displayed only when the project is built again. So the piecharts which are displayed are of the values of prvious run. If i run the code and make piecharts, these will be shown when i build the project and run again. Hence there is a lag. How to display the current piechart without building the project again on the same run? Help me out here please.

```
<jsp:useBean id="radioques" scope="page" class="abc.radioques" />
<%
String q[] = new String[44];
int j;
for (int i = 0; i < 44; i++) {
    j = 0;
    j = i + 1;
    q[i] = request.getParameter("question" + j);
}
radioques.rq(q);
%>
<jsp:useBean id="music" scope="page" class="abc.music" />

<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory" %> 
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart" %> 
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot3D" %> 
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset" %> 
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities" %> 
<%@ page import="java.lang.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.awt.Font"%>

<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.labels.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.MultiplePiePlot"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.general.DatasetUtilities"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.util.TableOrder"%>

<%@ page import="abc.radioques" %>

<%
radioques r = new radioques();
double temp[] = new double[5];
temp = r.rq(q);
DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
dataset.setValue("O+ = " + Math.round(temp[0]), (double) (temp[0]));
dataset.setValue("O- = " + Math.round(100 - temp[0]), (100 - (double) (temp[0])));

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
        "Openness", // chart title                   
        dataset, // data 
        true, // include legend                   
        true,
        false);

final PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
plot.setStartAngle(270);
plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.60f);
plot.setInteriorGap(0.02);
int width = 640; /* Width of the image */

int height = 480; /* Height of the image */

File pieChart3D = new File("C:/Users/Prashant/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication4/web/piecharts/pie3D.jpeg");
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(pieChart3D, chart, width, height);

DefaultPieDataset dataset1 = new DefaultPieDataset();
dataset1.setValue("C+ = " + Math.round(temp[1]), (double) (temp[1]));
dataset1.setValue("C- = " + Math.round(100 - temp[1]), (100 - (double) (temp[1])));

JFreeChart chart1 = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
        "Conscientiousness", // chart title                   
        dataset1, // data 
        true, // include legend                   
        true,
        false);

final PiePlot3D plot1 = (PiePlot3D) chart1.getPlot();
plot1.setStartAngle(270);
plot1.setForegroundAlpha(0.60f);
plot1.setInteriorGap(0.02);
int width1 = 640; /* Width of the image */

int height1 = 480; /* Height of the image */

File pieChart3D1 = new File("C:/Users/Prashant/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication4/web/piecharts/pie3D1.jpeg");
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(pieChart3D1, chart1, width1, height1);

DefaultPieDataset dataset2 = new DefaultPieDataset();
dataset2.setValue("E+ = " + Math.round(temp[2]), (double) (temp[2]));
dataset2.setValue("E- = " + Math.round(100 - temp[2]), (100 - (double) (temp[2])));

JFreeChart chart2 = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
        "Extraversion", // chart title                   
        dataset2, // data 
        true, // include legend                   
        true,
        false);

final PiePlot3D plot2 = (PiePlot3D) chart2.getPlot();
plot2.setStartAngle(270);
plot2.setForegroundAlpha(0.60f);
plot1.setInteriorGap(0.02);
int width2 = 640; /* Width of the image */

int height2 = 480; /* Height of the image */

File pieChart3D2 = new File("C:/Users/Prashant/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication4/web/piecharts/pie3D2.jpeg");
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(pieChart3D2, chart2, width2, height2);

DefaultPieDataset dataset3 = new DefaultPieDataset();
dataset3.setValue("A+ = " + Math.round(temp[3]), (double) (temp[3]));
dataset3.setValue("A- = " + Math.round(100 - temp[3]), (100 - (double) (temp[3])));

JFreeChart chart3 = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
        "Agreeableness", // chart title                   
        dataset3, // data 
        true, // include legend                   
        true,
        false);

final PiePlot3D plot3 = (PiePlot3D) chart3.getPlot();
plot3.setStartAngle(270);
plot3.setForegroundAlpha(0.60f);
plot3.setInteriorGap(0.02);
int width3 = 640; /* Width of the image */

int height3 = 480; /* Height of the image */

File pieChart3D3 = new File("C:/Users/Prashant/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication4/web/piecharts/pie3D3.jpeg");
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(pieChart3D3, chart3, width3, height3);
DefaultPieDataset dataset4 = new DefaultPieDataset();
dataset4.setValue("N+ = " + Math.round(temp[4]), (double) (temp[4]));
dataset4.setValue("N- = " + Math.round(100 - temp[4]), (100 - (double) (temp[4])));

JFreeChart chart4 = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
        "Neuroticism", // chart title                   
        dataset4, // data 
        true, // include legend                   
        true,
        false);

final PiePlot3D plot4 = (PiePlot3D) chart4.getPlot();
plot4.setStartAngle(270);
plot4.setForegroundAlpha(0.60f);
plot4.setInteriorGap(0.02);
int width4 = 640; /* Width of the image */

int height4 = 480; /* Height of the image */

File pieChart3D4 = new File("C:/Users/Prashant/Documents/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication4/web/piecharts/pie3D4.jpeg");
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(pieChart3D4, chart4, width4, height4);

music.selectsongs(temp);


%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Your Personality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss2.css">
</head>





<body>
    <h1>Your Personality</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Your OCEAN Traits Values</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="t1" align="left">
                    <img src="piecharts/pie3D.jpeg" width="342px">
                </td>
                <td class="t1" align="center">
                    <img src="piecharts/pie3D1.jpeg" width="342px">
                </td>
                <td class="t1" align="right">
                    <img src="piecharts/pie3D2.jpeg" width="342px">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="t1" align="left">
                    <img src="piecharts/pie3D3.jpeg" width="342px">
                </td>
                <td class="t1" align="center">
                    <img src="piecharts/pie3D4.jpeg" width="342px">
                </td>
                <td align="middle" align="center">
                    <form name="ocean" action="page3.jsp"  method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" width="100" height="50" name="Next2" value="Next" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part about grammar.

Comment: I closed your [previous question on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36524001/230513); going forward, please edit your question rather than asking essentially the same question again.

Comment: Instead of `saveChartAsJPEG()`, consider `writeChartAsJPEG()` as a way to avoid the file system.

Comment: @trashgod if i use `writeChartAsJPEG()` then it doesn't support it and says the file cannot be converted to OutputStream.

Comment: Write to the `OutputStream` from the servlet's `response`.

Comment: @trashgod i am sorry. didn't work. any better idea?